# Cannot set dynamic value for the property

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the specific string which is set in the language file like below

```
var resource_eng = {
    name_validation: "Please enter a valid name."
}
```

Here is my resource class method which is trying to get the string (Does not work)

```
static getCustomResourceData(value) {
    return resourceData.value;
}
```

I'm setting the value dynamically via

```
getCustomResourceData(this.props.id)
```

Setting static value works

```
static getCustomResourceData(value) {
     return resourceData.name_validation;
}
```

The above return correct string because i set it manually, but i want to be to set it dynamically from value parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static getCustomResourceData(value) {
    return resourceData[value];
}
```